# Как корректно посчитать количество минут с определенного момента?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть дата начала процесса в строчном виде:
`'2020-03-02 06:49:05'`

И дата завершения процесса:
`'2020-03-02 07:05:02'`

Вопрос:
Как корректнее всего с точки зрения подхода - подсчитать разницу(в минутах) между стартом и финишом процесса?
(если в `vue.js` или `nuxt.js` есть какие то встроенные методы для этого - то будет очень интересно о них так же узнать.)

Comment: `(new Date('2020-03-02 07:05:02'.replace(' ', 'T')) - new Date('2020-03-02 06:49:05'.replace(' ', 'T'))) / 60000`. Будет работать и без `replace`, но уже негарантированно.

Comment: Без таймзоны в дни перехода на летнее/зимнее время результат вообще говоря не однозначен.